# Can we add a URL redirect for Stack Apps?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, stackapps, redirection

I never remember the URL of the [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) site, and when I tried (and failed) http://apps.stackexchange.com I thought it would be a nice redirect. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Pointless snide remark: You can't remember the URL http://stackapps.com/ but you can remember the site is called "Stack Apps"? *Hmmm...*

Comment: True; didn't remember of the stackapps.com URL because I didn't remember the site name, but I first thought of apps.se.com because it's apps for stackexchange

Comment: done the same thing several times.

Answer (score 7):

Sort of ties in well with

- http://shop.stackexchange.com
- http://data.stackexchange.com

etc